# How to disable VSCode pop-up "You don't have an extension for debugging"?

Tags: visual-studio-code

VSCode started to spam me with the following pop-up:

> You don't have an extension for debugging Solidity.

I don't need an extension for debugging Solidity. How can I disable this pop-up?

Comment: So what are you doing now to debug?

Comment: A command-line interface tool. But that's not relevant.

Comment: I guess where I was going is that popup only shows when you try to debug through VSCode as far as I know. If you aren't doing that shouldn't you not see this message?

Comment: Well, exactly! I am not attempting to debug my code but VSCode nags me about getting an extension for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing Solidity development using Hardhat and VSCode. I don't think I've gotten the message since I added this to settings.json:

`"extensions.ignoreRecommendations": true,`

This is what my settings.json looks like:

```
{
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx": "zsh",
"hardhat.telemetry": true,

"extensions.ignoreRecommendations": true,

"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "javascriptreact"
  }
```

}

But I could be wrong.

Comment: I have this in my user and workspace settings but I'm still being yanked out of my code and thrown into a marketplace search because of these ridiculous dialogs.